# Segmentation fault on boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Im getting segmentation fault from pthread_mutex_lock, heres my backtrace:

```
    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff61b03f0 in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff61b03f0 in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x000000000041141f in boost::asio::detail::posix_mutex::lock (this=0x1)
    at /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/posix_mutex.hpp:71
#2  0x00000000004242ee in boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<boost::asio::ip::tcp, boost::asio::socket_acceptor_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >::basic_socket_acceptor(boost::asio::io_service&, boost::asio::ip::basic_endpoint<boost::asio::ip::tcp> const&, bool) ()
#3  0x000000000041c7df in Server (this=0x7fffffffe210) at src/server.cpp:12
#4  0x00000000004280bd in main () at src/main.cpp:21
(gdb)
```

my code:

```
#include "server.h"

#include "client.h"



#include <iostream>

#include <boost/thread.hpp>

#include <boost/bind.hpp>



#include "defines.h"



#include "server.h"
#include "client.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

#include "defines.h"

Irc::Server::Server()
{
    //
}

Irc::Server::~Server()
{
    m_clients.clear();
}

void Irc::Server::start()
{
    m_acceptor = new boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor(io);
}

void Irc::Server::startAccept()
{
    SocketPtr p(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(io));
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *resolver.resolve(query);
    m_acceptor->open(endpoint.protocol());
    m_acceptor->set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
    m_acceptor->bind(endpoint);
    m_acceptor->listen();
    m_acceptor->async_accept(*p,
        boost::bind(&Irc::Server::clientHandler, this, 
        p));
}

void Irc::Server::clientHandler(SocketPtr newSocket)
{
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> ThreadsPool;
    typedef std::vector<ThreadsPool> Threads;
    Threads threads;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        ThreadsPool p(new boost::thread(boost::bind(
            &boost::asio::io_service::run, &io)));
        threads.push_back(p);
    }
    for (Threads::iterator it = threads.begin(); it != threads.end(); ++it)
        (*it)->join();

    ClientPtr p(new Client(newSocket));
    m_clients[newSocket] = p;
    SocketPtr new_(new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(io));
    m_acceptor->async_accept(*new_,
        boost::bind(&Irc::Server::clientHandler, this, new_));
}


#ifndef SERVER_H
#define SERVER_H

namespace Irc
{
    class Client;
    class Server;
} //namespace Irc

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <map>

typedef boost::shared_ptr<Irc::Client> ClientPtr;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> SocketPtr;
typedef std::map<SocketPtr, ClientPtr> ClientsMap;

class Irc::Server
{
    public:
        Server();
        ~Server();

        void start();

        void startAccept();

        void clientHandler(SocketPtr);

        ClientsMap::iterator begin() { return m_clients.begin(); }
        ClientsMap::iterator end() { return m_clients.end(); }

    private:
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor* m_acceptor;
        boost::asio::io_service io;
        ClientsMap m_clients;
};
#endif
```

Comment: Since it comes from the constructor of m_acceptor, I can only guess that the io object given as parameter is not properly initialized.

Comment: Yes, but for example if the Server object and io are defined in the same scope, the Server contstructor might be called before the constructor for io. You could maybe post some more code.

Comment: Post the Irc::Server class definition

Comment: @Fallen please format your code. Do the line numbers in your stack trace agree with the code you've posted here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to post more code (Server::Server()) and post the files in separate code blocks for readability.

Try changing io to be a pointer, and explicitly initializing it in your constructor:

```
Irc::Server::Server() : io()
{
    start();
    startAccept();
}
```